# Openldap unexpectedly shutdown

Tags: openldap

I installed `openldap 2.4.35` from source tarball with `berkeleydb 5.0.32.NC` on `CentSO 6.4 x86_64`.

After running a few days , the `ldap` server shutdown unexpectedly. And here is the last log:

```
ber_get_next
TLS trace: SSL3 alert read:warning:close notify 
52b7b798 ber_get_next on fd 13 failed errno=0 (Success)
52b7b798 conn=1023 op=70 do_unbind
52b7b798 connection_close: conn=1023 sd=13
TLS trace: SSL3 alert write:warning:close notify
52b7cbba daemon: shutdown requested and initiated.
52b7cbba slapd shutdown: waiting for 0 operations/tasks to finish
52b7cbba slapd shutdown: initiated
52b7cbba ====> bdb_cache_release_all
52b7cbba slapd destroy: freeing system resources.
52b7cbba slapd stopped.
```

The configuration file (`slapd.conf`):

```
include         /home/ucportal/local/openldap/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /home/ucportal/local/openldap/etc/openldap/schema/corba.schema
include         /home/ucportal/local/openldap/etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /home/ucportal/local/openldap/etc/openldap/schema/duaconf.schema
include         /home/ucportal/local/openldap/etc/openldap/schema/dyngroup.schema
include         /home/ucportal/local/openldap/etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /home/ucportal/local/openldap/etc/openldap/schema/java.schema
include         /home/ucportal/local/openldap/etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include         /home/ucportal/local/openldap/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /home/ucportal/local/openldap/etc/openldap/schema/openldap.schema
include         /home/ucportal/local/openldap/etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema
include         /home/ucportal/local/openldap/etc/openldap/schema/collective.schema
include         /home/ucportal/local/openldap/etc/openldap/schema/uc.schema

pidfile         /home/ucportal/local/openldap/var/run/slapd.pid
argsfile        /home/ucportal/local/openldap/var/run/slapd.args

loglevel        1
logfile /home/ucportal/openldap/var/log/slapd.log

database        bdb
suffix          "dc=ucweb,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=admin,dc=ucweb,dc=com"

rootpw  123456

directory       /home/ucportal/local/openldap/var/openldap-data

index   objectClass     eq
index entryUUID,entryCSN eq

TLSCACertificateFile /home/ucportal/openldap/etc/openldap/cacerts/ca.crt
TLSCertificateFile /home/ucportal/openldap/etc/openldap/ldap-server.crt
TLSCertificateKeyFile /home/ucportal/openldap/etc/openldap/ldap-key.pem
```

Attention : I installed and run openldap with **non-root** user

I used this command to start ldap daemon process: `slapd -f ~/openldap/etc/openldap/slapd.conf -d 1 -h 'ldaps://0.0.0.0:6361'`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Somebody shut it down. The `close_notify` is part of an erroneous SSL session, not relevant to this.

Comment: but i'm sure that there is nobody logging on to that server

Comment: not enough data and the SSL alert is irrelevant. can you run it once again with -d 4 , and share the logs ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common issue with Open-**LDAP** servers, firstly I'll recommend you to migrate this question to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/). This will be a good practice to always run your daemons with root priviledges.

Based on my so far research I'd like to share these links with you, I hope they may help you to fix your problems.

- http://www.clearfoundation.com/component/option,com_kunena/Itemid,232/catid,10/func,view/id,19945/
- http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200502/msg00268.html

**Configure OpenLDAP**

- https://serverfault.com/questions/138286/configuring-openldap-and-ssl
- http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html

Comment: If you configure it correctly...chances are rare that it may shutdown, As you know prevention is better than cure...

Comment: I am afraid i have no root privilege to run the openldap as  daemons process, but i will try to follow your suggestion. Thank you